# Data lines disappearing when using rangePoints on x-axis ordinal scale in line chart with D3

Tags: d3.js

I've adapted this code from the multi-line line chart example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955). The biggest issue I'm now having after researching what changes I needed to make is that the data lines disappear when I use .rangePoints on the x-axis ordinal scale. With just .range, the x-axis displays nothing and the data lines are bunched up along the left side of the y-axis. This has something to do with the fact I altered the original code from a time scale to ordinal, but I'm stumped as to what further changes I need to make.

Code below:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 280 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
.rangePoints([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
.range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
.interpolate("linear")
.x(function(d) { return x(d.episodes); })
.y(function(d) { return y(d.season); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "episodes"; }));

var seasons = color.domain().map(function(name) {
return {
  name: name,
  values: data.map(function(d) {
    return {date: d.episodes, season: +d[name]};
  })
    };
  });

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.episodes; }));

  y.domain([
d3.min(seasons, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.season; }); }),
d3.max(seasons, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.season; }); })
  ]);

  svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Viewership (in mlns)");

  var s = svg.selectAll(".city")
  .data(seasons)
.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "city");

  s.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
  .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

  s.append("text")
  .datum(function(d) { return {name: d.name, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.season) + ")"; })
  .attr("x", 3)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
});
```

Comment: If you use ordinal data, you need to map each input to each output explicitly. See [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#ordinal) for more.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Lars. I'm wondering how I might do that? I've chained the domain and rangePoint methods together within the d3.csv function, which yields nothing. That's the only solution I can clean from the rather convoluted documentation.

Comment: You need to set the `.rangePoints()` after setting the domain -- the points are calculated when you call that method.

Comment: I should have been clearer in my last post: I chained .rangePoints() after setting the domain, as per the documentation, but that's solved nothing. My code for the call:  
    `x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.episodes;})).rangePoints([0,width]);`

Comment: Well the labels may need some work, but apart from that I'm having no trouble: http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/10680420

Comment: Thanks for your help, Lars. Your example helped point the way. I revisited my code and there was a more fundamental problem with it beyond the .rangePoints issue (though it was still a problem). I've now fixed it and everything works perfectly.